# Eclipse bug: This project has the JPA facet, but no JPA project could be created

Tags: eclipse, jpa-2.0

After restarting Eclipse, I get the following error in my project:

> This project has the JPA facet, but no JPA project could be created. See the error log for more details.

Nothing I've done (clean project, maven update, etc) will get rid of the error. My JPA Content icon remains greyed out.

[image]

It looks like this was a [resolved bug at Eclipse bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=380182)...but then why am I still getting it? **Should I submit a bug report to Eclipse?**

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: Same problem for me. Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: I never solved it. I ended up just starting over in a new Eclipse project. Luckily, it hasn't shown up in that one!

Answer (score 44):

This is a configuration problem of the project. To solve this problem go to the project properties, and in the node "project facets" unchecked JPA and apply the changes. Now you can checked JPA and apply again!

Comment: I checked out a project of svn that had that flag turned on, while I didn't have that JPA flag marked and still got this error. To solve this I had to mark JPA flag, apply than un-mark it

Comment: does not work for me (maven project with jpa enabled)

Comment: If the facet is locked you can go to `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` and remove the   `<installed facet="jpt.jpa" version="2.0"/>` section. Refresh the project. Put the section back where it was. Refresh the project again.

Comment: I just ran into this problem after importing a project into Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.3, and this answer fixed it.

Answer (score 24):

For me all the above didnt worked.

So I tried Project Properties>Validate. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

To get rid of this error in Eclipse Luna, I just did a right-click on the project and chose the "Validate" menu item.

Answer (score 3):

1. `Alt+Enter` in the project
2. Go for `Project facets`
3. **Uncheck** `JPA` and accept
4. Right click in the project, go for `Validate`
5. `Alt+Enter` in the project
6. Go for `Project facets`
7. **Check** JPA` and accept

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old thread, will try to give info that might just help someone.

I assume you have imported a project and it is giving this error.

Step 1 : Check under project properties if jpa is configured.

Step 2 : I have used eclipseLink as the user library for jpa. If you are using eclipse as well, try installing the plugin.

Step 3 : Check the version of jpa under project properties-> project facets... check for any conflicts in version, usually seen for java version and or any supporting libs. You should be able to change the version from facets.

JPA installation and configuration [JPA installation and config](http://www.javabeat.net/eclipselink-jpa-installation-configuration/)

Step 4 : once JPA is configured for the project, clean and check. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it by installing both apt and jdt connectors for m2e.

Go to **Window** > **Preferences** > **Maven** > **Discovery** > **Open Catalog**. Look for **m2e-apt** and **m2e-jdt-compiler**. Install and then restart eclipse.

Comment: OK for me - I just installed jdt connectors for m2e (and not apt). After restart error was still present; I had to "update Project" with Maven Eclipse and after it was OK.

Answer (score 1):

Click right button on **your project-->properties-->validation-->uncheck JPA Validation** .

That works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in some cases caused by a missing JPA implementation in the classpath. After I added a Maven (test scope) dependency, the Eclipse error message disappeared:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I this special case I had a "war" project that has a "persistence.xml" but no JPA code itself. The JPA stuff is in the referenced libraries (JARs).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was enough to clean the project.
Trying to disable JPA in the facet window caused an Exception.

Answer (score -2):

Like kaushikjain said, validate your project and the error will disappear. This worked like a charm to me.

Right click in your project and Validate.

[image]

Comment: May have worked for you, but it's not a proper answer, just a suggestion, it didn't for me.

Answer (score -3):

If you do not want to use JPA,
simply restart your eclipse and clean the project.

I had same problem when I copied JPA Entity to non-JPA project.
It worked for me and I hope it does so for yours :)